# Displaying a returned value when a button is pressed?

Tags: java, awt

I have some code here that calculates the maxValue of an array:

```
 public static int getMaxValue(int[] marks){
     int maxValue = marks[0];
     for(int i=1;i < marks.length;i++){
         if(marks[i] > maxValue){
             maxValue = marks[i];
         }
     }
     return maxValue;
 }
```

I want to display the maxvalue when a button is pressed by the user. This is what I have so far but it does not work:

```
private void analyzeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    maxValue mv = new maxValue ();
    analyzeTextArea.setText("Maximum:" + maxValue.toString());

}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: have you tried switching maxValue.toString() to maxValue.getMaxValue(intArray);

Comment: what happens when you try this.. ?

Comment: @ria Error saying, "Cannot find symbol: variable maxValue"

Comment: @user1320716 For you code I get an error saying, "Cannot find symbol: variable intArray" and "Cannot find symbol: variable maxValue"

Comment: yes.. maxValue is not in scope of your analyzeButtonActionPerformed method, as suggested in one of the below answers you can directly call the static method getMaxValue on the class that contains the static method..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this...

```
private void analyzeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    analyzeTextArea.setText("Maximum:" + getMaxValue(arrayOfValues));
}
```

To call a method, you don't need to do anything other than call `methodName(inputValues)` - you can't create an instance of the method by doing `new methodName()`

If the method is in a different class, and it is a `static` method like your case, you can do this...

```
private void analyzeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    analyzeTextArea.setText("Maximum:" + MyClass.getMaxValue(arrayOfValues));
}
```

Otherwise if the method is in a different class and it isn't `static`, then you create an instance of the class first, then call the method...

```
private void analyzeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    MyClass example = new MyClass();
    analyzeTextArea.setText("Maximum:" + example.getMaxValue(arrayOfValues));
}
```

Comment: This works as long as this piece of code is in the same class (although it likely is, good to watch out for edge cases).

Comment: It's not in the same class, I declared the maxValue method right after the array which is just below the import statements.

Comment: Agreed - I was taking it to be part of the same class, as its homework and looks like it might be a pretty simple requirement. However, your comment is correct, so I've added some additional information to my answer to cover these cases. Thanks

Comment: @user1419306 please see my edited answer for using a different ClassName. You also need to change the value `arrayOfValues` to the name of your array, and MyClass to the name of the class that contains the `getMaxValue()` method.

Comment: The name of the array is "marks" but isn't the name of the class "getMaxValue"?

Comment: @user1419306: The name of the *method* is `getMaxValue()`.  The name of the *class* is whatever file `getMaxValue()` resides in (or more specifically, the specific name of the class that contains the method `getMaxValue()`).

Comment: No, the name of the *method* is `getMaxValue()` - the name of the class is usually the same as the name of the *.java file. For example, the `Example.java` file usually has the class `Example`, and would be defined in the code of this *.java file as `public class Example {`

Comment: @Makoto and WATTO Studios Thanks, got the class name.

Comment: Now I get this error though, "required: int[] found: java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Intger>

Comment: This is what the assignment requires:  Each one of the following analyses (maximum, minimum, average, etc.) needs to be done in a separate method which will return the result of the analysis back to the analysis button's actionPerformed method. You can then display all the results from this method.

Comment: I think I'm doing something seriously wrong here, maybe I should have that method (maxvalue) within the button class?

Comment: Would you guys be willing to check it if I uploaded a zipped file?

Comment: My suggestion: why don't you 'tick' to accept one of our answers, as we have answered the original question, and then open a new question that has all your source code in it, explaining what you are trying to do, and what errors you are having. Maybe we'll be able to better fix your problems.

Comment: Ticked and opened new question (yesterday): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779228/marks-program-calculations

Answer (score 1):

Since your method is static, you can simply use the name of the class that contains it to call it.

```
analyzeTextArea.setText("Maximum:" + YourClassNameHere.getMaxValue());
```

You can't instantiate a method.

Comment: @user1419306,  I think getMaxValue needs a required parameter, int[] type. However I feel the function call looks awkward. It seems better that getMaxValue does not require a parameter. Perhaps, remove the class maxValue and make the function getMaxValue a function inside the interested class.

Comment: I tried this and pretty much the whole program is filled with errors.

Comment: @user1419306:  You can't copy the code *verbatim*; I'm giving you an example of what you need to use.  If the method is static, you use the class name, and pass in whatever parameters it needs.  (Really though, an accessor shouldn't need a parameter - if you wanted it to *calculate* the max value though, you should rename it; it confuses programmers easily.)