# Marks Program Calculations?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have to make a marks program that displays a set of marks that a user enters and some calculations (average, maximum, minimum, range, etc.). It should also be able to sort the marks in ascending order. I managed (with help) to display the marks and sort them but I cannot get the program to do the calculations and display them. This is all the code I have so far:

```
 ArrayList <Integer> marks = new ArrayList();

 private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Collections.addAll(marks, (Integer.parseInt(markInput.getText())));

    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    for (Integer mark: marks) {
    text.append(mark.toString()).append('\n');
    }

    markdisplayTextArea.setText(text.toString());
    }

 private void sortButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Collections.sort(marks);

    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    for (Integer mark: marks) {
    text.append(mark.toString()).append('\n');
    }

    markdisplayTextArea.setText(text.toString());
    }

 private void analyzeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    analyzeTextArea.setText("Class average:" +);
    analyzeTextArea.setText("Maximum mark:" +);
    analyzeTextArea.setText("Minimum mark:" +);
    analyzeTextArea.setText("Range of marks:" +);
    }
```

The calculations must be displayed in a `TextArea` when the `"analyze"` button is pressed. I currently have no idea of how to go about doing the calculations or displaying them. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my suggested code for your problem...

```
ArrayList<Integer> marks = new ArrayList<Integer>();

// Called when the user clicks a button
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object clickedButton = e.getSource();
    if(clickedButton == addButton) {
        addButtonActionPerformed();
    }
    else if(clickedButton == sortButton) {
        sortButtonActionPerformed();
    }
    else if(clickedButton == analyzeButton) {
        analyzeButtonActionPerformed();
    }
}

 private void addButtonActionPerformed() {
    Collections.addAll(marks, (Integer.parseInt(markInput.getText())));

    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    for (Integer mark: marks) {
        text.append(mark.toString()).append('\n');
    }

    markdisplayTextArea.setText(text.toString());
}

 private void sortButtonActionPerformed() {
    Collections.sort(marks);

    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    for (Integer mark: marks) {
        text.append(mark.toString()).append('\n');
    }

    markdisplayTextArea.setText(text.toString());
}

private void analyzeButtonActionPerformed() {

    String output = "Class average:" + calculateAverage() + "\n" +
                    "Maximum mark:" + calculateMaximum() + "\n" +
                    "Minimum mark:" + calcualteMinimum() + "\n" +
                    "Range of marks:" + calculateRange();

    analyzeTextArea.setText(output);
}

private int calculateAverage(){
    // calculate and return the answer
}

private int calculateMaximum(){
    // calculate and return the answer
    int maximum = 0;
    for (Integer currentMark: marks){
        if (currentMark > maximum){
            maximum = currentMark;
        }
    }
    return maximum;
}

private int calcualteMinimum(){
    // calculate and return the answer
}

private int calculateRange(){
    // calculate and return the answer
}
```

Now, these are my main changes, and why I made them...

1. I added a `actionPerformed()` method. If you don't have this already, it allows you to listen for button clicks. You need to add a line `myButton.addActionListener(this);` for each of your buttons. You'll probably also need to change your `public class MyClass` line to say `public class MyClass implements ActionListener`, and add a line `import java.awt.event.*`
2. I changed your `analyzeButtonActionPerformed()` method so that it outputs the values you requested. Now you need to implement the `calculate()` methods at the end - I have done one of them for you to give you the general idea. When you click the `analyze` button, it should do all the 4 calculations and put the answers in the `textarea`.

Why don't you have a bit of a look at my changes, and see whether you can see what they're supposed to be doing. Have a go at implementing some of the changes, and the calculate methods, and see if you can get it working. Don't just copy-paste my answer - make some changes bit-by-bit to see how it all works, and fix any compilation errors as they appear.

Comment: Is "int[] marks" what goes within the brackets here: private int calculateMaximum() Or is just the array name "marks"?

Comment: You don't need anything in the brackets. In the `calculateMaximum()` method, it is trying to use the variable called `marks`. Because the variable `marks` exist in the same class as this method, you don't need to include it in the brackets - you just have to write the word `marks` in your method and Java knows you mean the `ArrayList marks` at the top of your class.

Comment: This works great, thanks for all the help! Just to understand, what is currentmark? Also, I didn't have to add the actionPerformed() method since it works fine without it.

Comment: You're referring to the line `for (Integer currentMark: marks){`. What this does is, it loops (`for`) over every item in a list (`marks`), and the current item in the loop will have the variable name `currentMark`. So, if the marks are `20,50,10`, then the first time in this loop the value of `currentMark` will be `20`. The second time in the loop, the value of `currentMark` will be `50`. So, what the `calculateMaximum()` method does is, it has a variable `maximum` that holds the current maximum value. It loops through each mark 1 at a time, and if it is a larger value, thats the new `maximum`

Comment: No problems, glad to help. Nope, haven't heard of codecanyon before.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11848/discussion-between-user1419306-and-watto-studios)

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement `actionPerformed()` method and check for corresponding button clicked.

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==addButton) {
                        //do stuff
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==sortButton) {
              // do stuff
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==analyzeButton) {
              // do stuff
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'd advise against using `if` statements like this. At least use `else if` or a `switch`...